# Open a Google URL on button click

Tags: android

I have a button that when i click this button it opens google for me,  but when i run my code said unfortunately it stopped

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Context myContext=null;

ConnectivityManager connectMngr=(ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo=connectMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {if (netInfo==null || netInfo.isAvailable()==false||netInfo.isConnected()==false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
});
    }
```

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons to get _"unfortunately it stopped_" error. So please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40070406/edit) your question and post the logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

i. giving permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

ii. initializing the context in the **MainActivity**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

give these permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // initialize the  objects
    Context myContext = null;
    ConnectivityManager connectMngr ;
    NetworkInfo netInfo ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // passing this activity as the context
            myContext = MainActivity.this;
        // initializing the ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo class objects
            connectMngr = (ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            netInfo = connectMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {if (netInfo==null || netInfo.isAvailable()==false||netInfo.isConnected()==false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

                startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
});}
   }
```